# How to insert a CSS style into an SVG with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I try to add a CSS style sheet to an SVG. So what I have is the following svg:

```
<svg>
  <defs id="mydefs">
  </defs>
  <rect class="myclass" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20"/>
</svg>
```

And I would like to add a style sheet to this like:

```
<svg>
  <defs id="mydefs">
    <style type="text/css">
      .myclass {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="myclass" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20"/>
</svg>
```

I tried

```
var defs = document.getElementById('mydefs');
var style = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.insertRule('.myclass { fill: red; }', style.cssRules.length);
defs.appendChild(style);
```

But the `insertRule` (and `cssRules`) seems not to be supported. Here is the  (not working) codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEoLqg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works like this:

```
var defs = document.getElementById('mydefs');
var style = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'style');
defs.appendChild(style);
style.type = 'text/css';
style.sheet.insertRule('.myclass { fill: red; }', style.sheet.cssRules.length);
```

(BTW, you can also just use the parent document's style sheet:)

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
style.type = 'text/css';
style.sheet.insertRule('.myclass { fill: red; }');
```

The above approaches don't show any CSS in the inspector. If you need that, you could try something like the following instead:

```
var defs = document.getElementById('mydefs');
var style = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'style');
defs.appendChild(style);
style.innerHTML = '.myclass { fill: red; }';
```

---

**Update**: IE work-around as per Daniel's comment:

(The problem seems to be that IE does not support the .innerHTML for SVG elements.)

Use the `.innerHTML` of a `<div>` and set it to `<svg><style>.myclass { fill: red }</style></svg>` and then append all nodes in the `div`'s `.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` to the `style` element via:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(div.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes).forEach(function(el) {
    element.appendChild(el);
});
```

where `div` is the `<div>` element.

Comment: Hmm, where does the style go? I can't see it in the svg's `<defs>`. Am I missing something? Here is your code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EEoLqg

Comment: (I need the style to go into the svg since I am using it also as a standalone.)

Comment: Updated my post. Does this address what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, it does. At least in Firefox and Chrome. But for some reason IE 11 is not playing along.

Comment: Ah... Can't help with IE, sorry

Comment: @Daniel BTW, does IE neither apply the styles, nor show the code in the inspector? You could try doing both approaches at the same time for IE

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The problem seems to be that IE does not support the `.innerHTML` for SVG elements. A workaround I found is to instead use the `.innerHTML` of a `<div>` and set it to `<svg><style>.myclass { fill: red }</style></svg>` and then append all nodes in the div's `.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]` to the `style` element via `Array.prototype.slice.call(div.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes).forEach(function(el) { element.appendChild(el); });` where `div` is the `<div>` element.

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer or a reference to my comment.

Comment: Is the namespace necessary?